# How can I remove any row which has no cell comments in any column, in an excel 2010 spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with 85,000 rows and I need to extract just the cell comments, but it's currently too large, so I am wondering if I can write some VB (never done it before) or a macro or something that goes through each row, looks to see if any columns have a cell comment and if not, then deletes the row.

Any hints on how to achieve this would be appreciated! I have a programming background (and did some VB2-6 many, many years ago but have never programmed for Excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your sheet is active, replace "12" with the number of columns you are concerned with for `numColumns`.  Some `On Error` trickery is needed in `HasComment()` because `Comment.Text` errors if you try to check its value when it doesn't exist:

```
Sub RemoveRowsWithoutComments()
Dim rngAll As Range, rng As Range
Dim numColumns As Integer, colCntr As Integer, rowCntr As Long
Dim rowHasComment As Boolean

'set YOUR number of columns
numColumns = 12

Set rngAll = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

rowCntr = rngAll.Count - 1

'need to work backwards because deleting rows messes up forward iteration
Do Until rowCntr = -1

'work with current row (descending)
Set rng = Range("A1").Offset(rowCntr, 0)

rowHasComment = False

    For colCntr = 0 To numColumns

        If HasComment(rng.Offset(0, colCntr)) Then
            rowHasComment = True
            Exit For
        End If

    Next colCntr

    If Not rowHasComment Then rng.Rows.EntireRow.Delete

'decrement
rowCntr = rowCntr - 1
Loop
End Sub

Function HasComment(rng As Range) As Boolean
On Error GoTo NoComment

    If rng.Comment.Text <> "" Then
        HasComment = True
        Exit Function
    End If

NoComment:
    HasComment = False

End Function
```

Comment: You should accept my answer because it worked the first time, accounting for multiple comments, and more directly achieves the answer to your question, in fewer lines of code. :)  I'm just a lil guy trying to earn some rep on StackOF!

Comment: I found the bugs in your code and fixed it, basically the typo of cntr (should be colCntr) and it should be 0,colCntr in the call to HasComment and "Return" in HasComment should be "Exit Function".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Currently typing with my foot in my mouth.

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly different than what you asked for, but I think meets your needs.  It selects the rows with comments and pastes them, and an assumed header in row 1 into another sheet.  Change "Sheet1" to suit:

```
Sub PasteRowsWithComments()
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
Dim RowsWithComments As Excel.Range

Set wsSource = Sheet1
Set wsTarget = Worksheets.Add
On Error Resume Next
Set RowsWithComments = wsSource.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments).EntireRow
On Error GoTo 0
If Not RowsWithComments Is Nothing Then
    RowsWithComments.Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A1")
    wsSource.Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy
    wsTarget.Range("A1").Insert shift:=xlDown
End If
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Option Explicit

Dim RngToCopy As Range

Sub PasteRowsWithComments()
    Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim RowsWithComments As Excel.Range

    Set wsSource = Sheet1: Set wsTarget = Worksheets.Add

    On Error Resume Next
    Set RowsWithComments = wsSource.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments).EntireRow
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not RowsWithComments Is Nothing Then
        '~~> This is required to clean duplicate ranges so that we do not get
        '~~> the error "That command cannot be used on multiple selections"
        If InStr(1, RowsWithComments.Address, ",") Then _
        Set RngToCopy = cleanRange(RowsWithComments) Else _
        Set RngToCopy = RowsWithComments

        RngToCopy.Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Rows(1)
        wsSource.Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy
        wsTarget.Range("A1").Insert shift:=xlDown
    End If
End Sub

'~~> This function will convert `$1:$1,$1:$1,$4:$4,$7:$7` to `$1:$1,$4:$4,$7:$7`
Function cleanRange(rng As Range) As Range
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim Myarray() As String, sh As String, tmp As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim itm As Variant

    sh = rng.Parent.Name: Myarray = Split(rng.Address, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(Myarray)
        On Error Resume Next
        col.Add Myarray(i), """" & Myarray(i) & """"
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i

    For Each itm In col
        tmp = tmp & "," & itm
    Next

    tmp = Mid(tmp, 2): Set cleanRange = Sheets(sh).Range(tmp)
End Function
```

Comment: That would work, but when I try to run it I get an error on the line RowsWithComments.Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A1") which says "That command cannot be used on multiple selections"

Comment: +1 nicely coded Doug. @BenHolness I can't duplicate the error, typically you can resolve issues working with non-contigious ranges by looping through the `Areas` of the range (ie `For Each rng1 In RowsWithComments.Areas` etc)

Comment: @BenHolness, I kind of expected that type of problem, but in my limited test case of discontiguous ranges it didn't pop up, so left it as is.  As brettdj says, the answer lies in looping through the ranges.

Comment: +1 Nicely coded. I was able to replicate the error though. If you have two comments in the same row, you will get the error. Scenatio `$1:$1,$1:$1,$4:$4,$7:$7` is the `?RowsWithComments.Address `

Comment: I have a solution ready. If you want, I can edit your post and add it there? It combines nicely with your solution.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Nice work finding the issue.  And the solution works like a charm!